# Device keyboard is overlapping my bottom sheet in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm facing an issue where my Bottom Sheet is hided by my Keyboard and I'm not able to figure out why.

I found a lot of answers explaining a similar issue but none fixed my problem. Bellow you will be able to see the actual behaviour with two screenshots :
[image: This is before]
[image: This is after]

This is my code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Brightness brightnessValue =
        MediaQuery.of(context).platformBrightness;
    bool isDark = brightnessValue == Brightness.dark;
    return AnimatedPadding(
      padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
      curve: Curves.decelerate,
      child: SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2.5,
          child: BlocBuilder<WorkSiteBloc, WorkSiteState>(
              builder: (BuildContext context, WorkSiteState state) {
            return RotatedBox(
              quarterTurns: state.bottomsheetRotation,
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: const Radius.circular(30),
                        topRight: const Radius.circular(30))),
                child: ListView(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                          child: IconButton(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_left),
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                              showModalBottomSheet(
                                  context: context,
                                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                    return Container(
                                      color: Color(0xFF737373),
                                      child: ObservationBottomSheet(
                                          widget.index,
                                          widget.planIndex,
                                          widget.controller),
                                    );
                                  });
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          AppLocalizations.of(context).translate("Description"),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 18,
                              color: !isDark ? Colors.black54 : Colors.white70),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Divider(height: 00),
                    TextField(
                      controller: textController,
                      onChanged: (String text) {
                        setState(() {
                          description = text;
                        });
                      },
                    
                    
                      maxLines: 10,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          })),
    );
  }
```

Do you have any ideas what is causing this issue ?
Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging i found that the issue for me was that i was running flutter beta. After switching back to the stable channel the issue was fixed. It is a really good reminder for me that beta software should not be considered as production ready.

Thank you for the help and all the answers !

Comment: Please mark your answer as accepted so that, people can help others.

Comment: @PreetShah  I forced to wait 6 hours to mark  my answer as accepted

Comment: Cool. Just letting you know.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot see the custom widget you're going to show in your modal bottom sheet, but it must start with a **Padding** widget !

So wrap that with a *Padding* widget like this:

```
 return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
        bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
        ),     
      child: //your own implementations
      );
```

Also don't forget to set the configuration below in the modal sheet:

```
isScrollControlled: true
```

Hope that would be alright !

Comment: Thank you for your answer but after adding your piece of code inside the showModalBottomSheet builder I'm still getting the same result

Comment: Are you sure that you have a ShowModalBottomSheet with ( isScrollControlled: true ), then its builder directly returns a Container/Padding with the bottom padding mentioned, then its child is a Column ?

On android it works fine for me !

Comment: perfectly helped for me